# Mostrar los datos seleccionados de un select en un textarea

Tags: javascript, django

Soy nuevo en la programación en Django, por favor si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradezco.

Tengo un `select` donde las opciones son los objetos almacenados en la base de datos de un modelo llamado `Tema`, lo que quiero hacer es mostrar los atributos del  modelo seleccionado debajo del `select` en un `textarea`.

Este es el código de la vista:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView, DeleteView, CreateView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from forms import CreateRemedial, UpdateRemedial
from remedial.models import Remedial

class CreateRemedial(CreateView):

    model = Remedial
    form_class = CreateRemedial
    template_name = 'remedial/list-rem/create_r.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        new_rem = form.save()
        messages.success(self.request, 'Remedial creado satisfactoriamente', extra_tags='msg')
        url = reverse('update_remedial', kwargs=dict(pk=new_rem.pk))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print self.request.POST
        messages.error(self.request, 'Verifique los datos marcados en rojo', extra_tags='msg')
        return super(CreateRemedial, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Código del modelo:

```
from django.db import models
from tema.models import Tema

class Remedial(models.Model):
    description=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    tema=models.ForeignKey(Tema)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description
```

Código de la plantilla:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block menu %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Inicio</a></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Insertar remedial</li>
{% endblock %}
{% block title %}Insertar Remedial{% endblock %}
{% block new_r %}active{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="box box-primary flat">
            <div class="box-header">
                <h3 class="box-title"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> DATOS <span
                        class="small">del nuevo remedial</span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                <dl class="margin">
                    <form role="form" action="{% url 'create_remedial' %}" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin: -15px 0 0 0; padding-bottom:10px; ">
                           <label for="descrip">{{ form.description.label|escape }} <sup><sup><i
                                   class="fa fa-asterisk"></i></sup></sup></label>

                            <div class="form-group {% if form.description.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
                                {{ form.description }}
                                <small class="help-block">
                                    {% if form.description.errors %}{% for error in form.description.errors %}
                                        {{ error|escape }}
                                    {% endfor %}{% else %}{{ form.description.help_text|escape }}{% endif %}</small>
                            </div>
                             <div class="form-group {% if form.tema.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
                                {{ form.tema }}
                                <small class="help-block">
                                    {% if form.tema.errors %}{% for error in form.tema.errors %}
                                        {{ error|escape }}
                                    {% endfor %}{% else %}{{ form.tema.help_text|escape }}{% endif %}</small>
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-flat" name="only_save"><i
                                    class="fa fa-check"></i> Insertar
                            </button>
                            <a href="{% url 'list_remedial' %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat pull-right"><i
                                    class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i> Cancelar</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </dl>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Y el código del formulario:

```
class CreateRemedial(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model= Remedial

    description=forms.CharField(

        max_length=300,

        label='Descripción',

        help_text='Escriba los ejercicios que conforman el remedial',

        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'id': 'descrip',
                                      'class': 'form-control',
                                      'name': 'descrip1',
                                      'placeholder': 'Ejemplo: Ejercicio 3 del LT'
        })
    )
    tema=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Tema.objects.all(),empty_label='Seleccione un tema',help_text='Seleccione el tema al cual está vinculado el remedial')
```

Básicamente lo que quiero es poner dentro del formulario que tengo un `textarea` de tal forma que cuando lo despliegue y seleccione un tema se me muestre la descripción del mismo en el `textarea`.

Comment: Suena a que necesitas el evento `change` del `select` mezclado con alguna función AJAX que traiga lo que necesitas hacia tu `textarea`

Comment: Me puedes poner un ejmplo, o darme una idea de como se hace??

Comment: Claro, pero primero sería bueno que edites tu pregunta y pongas el código que tienes actualmente, incluye el modelo, tu vista, tu formulario y el template que estás usando. Así es más facil ayudarte en vez de hacer todo desde cero y asumir cosas

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Raudel. Por favor actualiza el contenido de tu pregunta, trata de colocar la información necesaria para que podamos entender mejor y replicar tu problema, así podremos ayudarte mejor. Sigue el consejo de @César :)

Comment: Gracias @César y Luiggi , ya edite mi pregunta espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: A ver si entiendo, lo que necesitas es que al escoger un `tema` del `select`, busque en la base de datos alguna instancia de  `Remedial` que tenga ese tema y jale la descripción. ¿Es correcto eso? De ser asi, ¿qué pasa si existen muchos remedial con el mismo tema? En ese caso tu campo `Remedial.tema` debería ser `unique=True`

Comment: nono yo lo ke quiero es ke al escoger un tema del select se me muestre la descripción del mismo en un textarea..Saludos de cuba y gracias por ayudarme

Answer (score 2):

Debes crear un AJAX que llame a un php donde busques los atributos del Model.
Te dejo el código de como sería el AJAX.

```
$('#idSelect').change( function() {
var selectVal = $('#idSelect').val();
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: "select=" + selectVal,
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/url_donde_tendras_el_php_que_consiga_los_datos_del_model",
        success: function (response) {
            for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++){
                $('#idTextArea').append(response[i]);
            }
        },

});
```

***Nota*** En el php recibes el valor del select por postpor lo que harías

```
$selectVal = $_POST['select'];
```